# How to use PHP foreach variable in js function

Tags: javascript, php

**GOAL**:
I'm trying to create a simple click-to-copy function which will allow a user to click on an image and have the image path copied to the clipboard.

**BACKGROUND**:

I have a simple form that presents images and a correlating input field with the image path as the value from the back-end server via PHP. In that form, I have a button (which is the image itself) which when clicked copies the image path (on the server, NOT relative) from the input field to the clipboard. So the image path to be copied to the clipboard would be something like "../img/picture.png".

The images and their input fields are parsed using PHP "foreach", so in order to get a unique input ID for the JS button to use, I assigned each input field an ID with a number generated by a PHP "$count" variable.  This all works great. The form looks like this:

[image]

**ISSUE**:

The images are parsed with a coorelating input field with their path. The input fields are also assigned a unique ID, however, when I click the button to copy their path, it will only copy the path of the last image on the form. It doesn't matter which button I press, only the last image path is copied. There's no errors in the browser console.

You'll see in the picture below that the js function is parsing the input IDs correctly, but for some reason, it only copies the path of the last image element that is loaded. So you'll see in the image that the image input field has an ID of "12" since it's the 12th image loaded, but if there were 18 images, it will only copy the 18th images' path despite clicking on any of the previous 17 images.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**CODE**:

```
       <div id="picform"> 

            <?php

                $dirname = '../img/';
                $images = glob($dirname.'*.*');

                $count = 0;

                foreach ($images as $image) {

                    echo '<div id="imgthumb">';

                        echo '<button id="imgbtn" onclick="copyFunction()">';
                            echo '<center>';
                                echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style="width:7rem" />';
                            echo '</center>';
                        echo '</button>';

                        echo '<div id="imgpath">';
                            echo '<input type="text" value="'.$image.'"  id="'.$count.'" name="imginput" readonly>';

                            ?>
                                <script>
                                    function copyFunction() {
                                        var count = '<?php echo json_encode($count);?>';
                                        var copyText = document.getElementById(count);
                                        copyText.select();
                                        document.execCommand("Copy");
                                    }
                                </script>
                            <?php

                        echo '</div>';

                    echo '</div>';

                    ++$count;

                }
            ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: *You're overwriting the function on each iteration*, instead of doing that, have a single function, on click the item store the selection, on click the copy button, use item to place into clipboard.

Comment: You're redefining `copyFunction` over and over again. The most recently echoed one becomes the only one.

Comment: right, I know this.  I only put the js function inline to show that it was parsing the IDs correctly.  Not leaving it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing JS in PHP is super confusing and not worth it. Just let PHP write HTML - that's confusing enough - then write JS which works with the HTML.

```
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgthumb');
thumbs.forEach( function ( thumb ) {
    var button = thumb.querySelector('button');
    var input = thumb.querySelector('input');
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        input.select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
    })
})
```

`imgthumb` and the rest should be classes, not IDs; you can only use an ID once.

Comment: that was it! THANK YOU SIR!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you re-define `copyFunction` in your script, that becomes the function that gets called when anything in your script calls `copyFunction`. Change it so that you only have one `copyFunction` function.

For example, perhaps change

`echo '<button id="imgbtn" onclick="copyFunction()">';`

to

`echo '<button id="imgbtn" onclick="copyFunction(' . $count . ')">';`

and only define `copyFunction` once somewhere else.

But using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code, as you're experiencing - it's as bad as `eval`. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

For example, you don't even need to use IDs to identify the input element to copy - instead, give `copyFunction` an `event` argument, and then check `event.target` to identify the button that was clicked, and from that, navigate to the `input` just below.

Comment: thanks for your response.   Right, I put the JS script inline to test if it was parsing the input IDs correctly,  I wasn't intending on leaving there.  As far as your solution, I can't seem to get it to work, when I tried editing the onclick fucntion to your suggestion, I get an "unexpected token"...I'm assuming because you're tying to use the PHP echo string when it's already in a PHP function itself?

Comment: It's tedious and easy to mess up when writing Javascript inside of PHP - don't do it, put your Javascript in a separate .js file instead. When you *do* need to communicate information from PHP to Javascript, use data- attributes, application/JSON, or XHR.

Comment: right, understood, however, if I do put it in a separate js file, that means I also have to an AJAX call to get the actual file paths.  I just thought this would be simple enough.  I'll look into it. Thx.

Comment: No you don't, just echo them into the HTML somewhere. `<button data-path="<?= $image ?>">`

Comment: @BenWest  I thought that's what I was doing in the first place? ```echo '<input type="text" value="'.$image.'"  id="'.$count.'" name="imginput" readonly>';```

Comment: If the file paths you want are in the HTML, you don't have to get them with AJAX.

Comment: @BenWest which leads me back to my original question. They are in the HTML. I guess I'm not understanding what to change in my code? All the img paths are there in the HTML, I guess my issue is passing the paths to JS?

Comment: Oh, got you. I'll write an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining the `copyFunction` every time the foreach executes,so when you call it the script calls the last one. Define it anywhere else and add a parameter where you can use the $count variable: `copyFunction(<?php echo json_encode($count);?>)`

Comment: Right, I had the js function inline to see if it was parsing the ID correctly.  however, when I move it outside the foreach tag, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null" in the console.